# Multiple selects within query

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

This query is building commodity symbols from an xml file.

The file structure is

```
<Commodities>
  <Grains>
    <Commodity title="Corn" value="0" name="corn">
      <Specs>
        //other elements
        <SymbolRoot>
          <Platform value="ZC" name="globex"/>
          <Platform value="C " name="bloomberg"/>
        </SymbolRoot>
      </Specs>
      <ContractMonths firstnoticedaterule="" lasttradedaterule="The business day prior to the 15th calendar day of the contract month">
        <Month value="Mar">
         <Year value="2018" firstnoticedate="02/28/18" lasttradedate="03/14/18" dateformat="mm/dd/yy"/>
          <Year value="2019" firstnoticedate="02/28/19" lasttradedate="03/14/19" dateformat="mm/dd/yy"/>
          <Year value="2020" firstnoticedate="02/28/20" lasttradedate="03/13/20" dateformat="mm/dd/yy"/>
        </Month>
      </ContractMonths>
    </Commodity>
  </Grains>
<Commodities>
```

For right now, I can get the contract months as needed, but I also need the symbol root for the platform passed in. Right now it is hardcoded as "C "

```
private List<string> GetAllSymbolsForContractMonths(CommodityList commodity, string platform)
{
    var symCode = string.Empty;
    var yrLastDigit = DateTime.Now.Year % 10;
    //get the contract month symbol codes
    var query = _doc.Descendants("Commodity")
            .Where(c => c.Attribute("name")?.Value == commodity.ToString().ToLower())
            .Descendants("ContractMonths").Elements("Month")
            .Select(v => "C " + SymbolHelpers.GetSymbolContractMonthLetter(v.Attribute("value")?.Value) + yrLastDigit + " Comdty")
            .ToList();

    return query;
}
```

I know there is some way to do a select on the value attribute of the Platform element and set that value to the symCode variable but I cant seem to get it right. Then I can just replace the hardcoding with the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your query in two.
First, find the commodity element.

From that element, find the platform symbol.
Then, build the list.

```
private List<string> GetTypeFromVariable(CommodityList commodity, string platform)
{
    var yrLastDigit = DateTime.Now.Year % 10;

    var commodityElement = _doc.Descendants("Commodity")
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("name")?.Value.Equals(commodity.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ?? false)
        .Single();

    var symbol = commodityElement.Descendants("Platform")
        .Where(x => x.Attribute("name")?.Value.Equals(platform, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ?? false)
        .Single()
        .Attribute("value").Value;

    return commodityElement
        .Descendants("ContractMonths").Elements("Month")
            .Select(v => symbol + " " + SymbolHelpers.GetSymbolContractMonthLetter(v.Attribute("value")?.Value) + yrLastDigit + " Comdty")
            .ToList();
}
```

Comment: By the way - to make this code testable, the year should be a parameter, not based on the clock of the computer.

Comment: @gnud...I figured as much. Was trying to do it in one shot. No way around that? Got you on the parameter for testability.

Comment: No reason to do it in one shot. The first part of the query, where you find the commodity element, has to run anyway. There won't be any performance difference. And it's a lot clearer to split it up.

Comment: @gnud...ty and I learned some new query tricks from that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just for kicks, there are some cool sites to convert your XML to C# classes (e.g. [Xml2CSharp.com](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)). Using the tool, you can create a set of classes to deserialize to and then leverage LINQ to Objects.

```
Commodities commodities = null;
using (var stream = new StringReader(xmlString))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Commodities));
    commodities = (Commodities) serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}

var commodityName = "corn";
var platformName = "bloomberg";
var year = "2018";
var commodity = commodities.Grains.Commodity.Single(c => c.Name.Equals(commodityName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
var symbol = commodity.Specs.SymbolRoot.Platform.Single(p => p.Name.Equals(platformName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
var months = commodity.ContractMonths.Month.Year.Where(y => y.Value.Equals(year, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Here are the classes I generated using the tool. It's obviously a lot more code but I like have concrete classes to work with. Hope it's helpful.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Platform")]
public class Platform
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "SymbolRoot")]
public class SymbolRoot
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Platform")]
    public List<Platform> Platform { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Specs")]
public class Specs
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SymbolRoot")]
    public SymbolRoot SymbolRoot { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Year")]
public class Year
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "firstnoticedate")]
    public string Firstnoticedate { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lasttradedate")]
    public string Lasttradedate { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "dateformat")]
    public string Dateformat { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Month")]
public class Month
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Year")]
    public List<Year> Year { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ContractMonths")]
public class ContractMonths
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Month")]
    public Month Month { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "firstnoticedaterule")]
    public string Firstnoticedaterule { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lasttradedaterule")]
    public string Lasttradedaterule { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Commodity")]
public class Commodity
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Specs")]
    public Specs Specs { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ContractMonths")]
    public ContractMonths ContractMonths { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Grains")]
public class Grains
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Commodity")]
    public List<Commodity> Commodity { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Commodities")]
public class Commodities
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Grains")]
    public Grains Grains { get; set; }
}
```